# Installed python package not able to find module in own directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-ads-api, pyenv

I recently got my new Macbook Pro and installed 3.8.6 with pyenv and created a virtualenv for my project. When I try to run the tests for this project i get the following error about a module not found by a dependency (abridged). The the files are all there, `ad_manager` is a file right next to the `__init__.py` file that is importing it. This was not a problem on my old machine.

`echo $PYTHONPATH` is empty

`python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'` -> `['', '/Users/derek/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python38.zip', '/Users/derek/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8', '/Users/derek/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/Users/derek/.pyenv/versions/VIRTUAL_ENV_3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages']`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/derek/dev/PATH_TO_PROJECT/tests/../src/services/adwords_service.py", line 18, in <module>
    from googleads import oauth2, adwords
  File "/Users/derek/.pyenv/versions/VIRTUAL_ENV_3.8.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleads/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ad_manager import AdManagerClient
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ad_manager'
```

Comment: What version of `googleads` do you have installed? The [current version of `__init__.py` on Github](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/googleads/__init__.py#L17) has `from .ad_manager import AdManagerClient`, not `from ad_manager import AdManagerClient`. That `.` makes a big difference.

Comment: `17.0.0` which is pinned for the project. I did modify that file and add `.` but it only pushed the issue to the next module import. I could try to upgrade to another version but not sure if that will break things for the project.

Comment: Change the next line to `from .adwords import AdWordsClient`. Does that fix it?

Comment: I mean imports within the ad_manager module. I'm suddenly having internet issues so I can't test v18.0.0, will get back to you when I can

Comment: did you solve it?